# Trying to center a "figure" tag in CSS (without using Div)

Tags: css, html

I am currently trying to create a website for the first time and I am having great difficulty in getting my 3 inline-block images to center properly in CSS.

I used the figure tag to title and display my images (that works fine no issue).

But when I came round to positioning the 3 images horizontally inline they will not move from the left of the screen despite my best efforts.

```
figure {
    text-align: center; 
    font-family: 'Rasa', serif;
    font-size: 18px; 
    display: inline-block;
    align-content: center;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
    float: center;
}
```

Any help in pointing out what I have done wrong or am missing I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: If your figures are inline-block, then their parents need to have `text-align: center` to center them. Also center is not a valid value for a float.

Comment: There's no such thing as `float:center`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
HTML:
<div class="figure">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

CSS:
.figure {
    text-align: center; 
    font-family: 'Rasa', serif;
    font-size: 18px; 
    display: inline-block;
    align-content: center;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
}
.box{
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  border:1px solid black;
  float:left;
}
```

[image: This is what it looks like]

Comment: I was aiming to do something like that yes. However I wanted spacing between the 3 images.

Comment: Thank you for the help, this has saved me so much time.